# Position/scale image after programmatically pasting it into bookmark range

Tags: image, insert, automation, ms-word

I'm creating a Word 2010 document using C# and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. Using the [Range.Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.paste.aspx) method, I insert a bitmap (from RAM) at a specified bookmark:

```
Word.Bookmark bookmark = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(image);
bookmark.Range.Paste();
```

This bookmark is placed inside a frame (created with the "Insert Frame" command), hence the pasted image is placed inside the frame. Now, the image is automatically scaled to fit the frame horizontally. This is good! But, it does not perform this type of scaling vertically! This causes the bottom of the image to be obscured by any object under the frame:

[image: Image not scaled vertically]

Frame A should not be resized!

**Q: How can I make sure the image is scaled both horizontally and vertically, keeping the frame's original size?**

Comment: Solved it using some complex stuff involving iterating through the document's frames and scaling the image before pasting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Read the size of the frame and then properly scale the image before pasting it.