# Edit inserted picture on a word document using c# interop

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

I want to edit an inserted picture (c&p) on a word document.
So I have this

```
chart.CopyPicture();                                              
bookmark.Range.Paste();
```

to copy it from my excel file and paste it into my word file. But now I have to edit it on my word file.
How can I find it to do so?

Comment: To be a little bit clearer:
in PPT I was able to do something like
shape = something.Paste(); because Paste() or PasteSpecial() returns a shape but it doesn't in word. Its void in word.
So shape = bookmark.Range.Paste() is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change shape, use [How to change the size of a picture after inserting it into a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483471/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-picture-after-inserting-it-into-a-word-document)

```
shape.Width = 150; 
shape.Height = 150;
```

Comment: But how can I find my picture or assign it to a shape?
On your link, he is using AddPicture() on a shape but you can not do something like 
shape.AddPicture(...Paste(),...) or paste(shape.range) or something like this.

Comment: You could try resizing the frame before pasting it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666624/position-scale-image-after-programmatically-pasting-it-into-bookmark-range

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find your picture under bookmark.Range.ShapeRange or bookmark.Range.InlineShapes

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195321.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837242.aspx